# camera controller is not working as intended as player moves & jumps

Tags: c#, controller, camera, character, unity-game-engine

[EDIT] Changed title due to additional issues.

Whenever player moves, it draws arc to move. Whenever player jumps, camera controller zooms in first and then zoom out trying to fix its position. I want it to stay zoomed out while jumping (just realized how huge work this question could become...with "unless colliding or interfered its view with other objects"). I also want it to move, well, properly. (Just by movement without additional line of code related to camera script works perfect)

My player controller is [default character controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) script from Unity Documentation. My camera controller is based on [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txug_X8hlI0&index=3&list=PL4CCSwmU04MjDqjY_gdroxHe85Ex5Q6Dy). I know why it's causing trouble because I used different character controller than the tutorial used but that's because his character controller didn't work with mine. So I'm trying to fix while having default character controller.

[EDIT] After looking into the script for sometime I was able to narrow it down to one of possible culprits.

```
Vector3 camVel = Vector3.zero;

void MoveToTarget()
{
    targetPos = target.position + position.targetPosOffset;
    destination = Quaternion.Euler (orbit.xRotation, orbit.yRotation + target.eulerAngles.y, 0) * -Vector3.forward * position.distanceFromTarget;
    destination += targetPos;

    if (collision.colliding) 
    {
        ////from here
        adjustedDestination = Quaternion.Euler (orbit.xRotation, orbit.yRotation + target.eulerAngles.y, 0) * Vector3.forward * position.adjustmentDistance;
        adjustedDestination += targetPos;

        if (position.smoothFollow)
        {
            //use smooth damp function
            ////to here makes weird behavior. Found out with debug.log line.
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, adjustedDestination, ref camVel, position.smooth);
        }
        else
            transform.position = adjustedDestination;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (position.smoothFollow) 
        {
            //use smooth damp function                
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, destination, ref camVel, position.smooth);
        }  
        else
            transform.position = destination;
    }
}
```

target is getting reference from TPController, which is character controller below. Though I still don't understand why this is happening (It didn't happen in tutorial video). Unless...my character controller is somehow interfering with camera controller.

```
public Quaternion TargetRotation
{
    get { return targetRotation; }
}

void Start() {
    targetRotation = transform.rotation;
}

void Update() {
    Movement ();
    Turn ();
}

void Movement()
{
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}

void Turn() 
{
    if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")) > inputDelay) 
    {
        targetRotation *= Quaternion.AngleAxis (rotateVel * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, Vector3.up);
    }
    transform.rotation = targetRotation;
}
```

disabling Turn() does allow character to move without drawing arc. But then camera doesn't turn around as character turns. ///**this arc movement part is solved** - leaving it here for future reference in case any one tries similar method: in the section of

```
moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
```

put 0 instead of Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"). Should be able to move without drawing arc.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: My guess is that **you have posted irrelevant code**.

Comment: m.rogalski // uh...can you be a bit more brief than that? I only have 2 scripts in the scene. Player, and camera controller. And if you say irrelevant code...I'd love to post a whole script here, but it's 1k+ codes.

Comment: by irrelevant he means that you posted just methods names we dont know what is happening inside them  **be sure to post the code where you think the problem is or by Which you think the problem can be identified**
as you can see there are just methods in your snippet
**Try to identify the problem by yourself first then ask for suggestions**
as i can not understand why u said there is a problem in check colliding method cause i can not see its code